# The if condition doesn't stop being enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a bot for my school, and i'm currently developing a feature that enables students to talk in a voice channel if the student sent a specific message and if the teacher reacted to it with a specific emoji. Here is the code.

```js
client.on('message', handMsg => {
  if (!handRaiseModeActive) return;
  if ((handMsg.content.includes(PREFIX + 'talk')) && handMsg.channel.id === hgCID) {
    superConsole(`**@${handMsg.author.tag} asked to speak ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||**`)
    handMsg.react('✅')
    handMsg.react('❎')
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

      if (reaction._emoji.name == '✅' && user.id !== botID && (user.id == teacherID || devID.includes(user.id))) {
        handMsg.member.voice.setMute(false)
        handMsg.reactions.removeAll();
        superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak given to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
      } else if (reaction._emoji.name == '❎' && user.id !== botID && (user.id == teacherID || devID.includes(user.id))) {
        handMsg.reactions.removeAll()
        superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak denied to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
      }

    });
  }
})
```

`teacherID` is the ID of the teacher, `devID` is an array with all the dev IDs, and `botID`... the bot ID. A command puts `handRaiseModeActive` on true or false. `superConsole` is a function in which the event is sent on a channel and in the console.

And here is my problem:
The first time a student asks the permission to speak, everything works fine, but if, afterwards, another student gets the permission to speak with the handRaiseMode, all students who have previously asked to speak are unmuted... It seems like the `l.3` is still working despite the fact it should have ended. I don't really understand how it works. Need help!

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue then please accept it to let others know what worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be because you are nesting your events, that is a bad habit regardless as it can cause memory leaks and whatnot.

I think your issue can be simply fixed using [`awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) instead:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['✅', '❎'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (user.id == teacherID || devID.includes(user.id))
};

handMsg.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
            handMsg.member.voice.setMute(false)
            handMsg.reactions.removeAll();
            superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak given to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
        } else {
            handMsg.reactions.removeAll()
            superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak denied to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        handMsg.reply('the teacher did not give you permission in time!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, Really cool idea you have! Wish my school used discord Would be a blast to code a bot for them :)

If you have any problems with this code feel free to comment and i'll fix it

Note: I've tested this code and it seems to work for me, I used these values/functions for testing

```js
handRaiseModeActive = true;

function superConsole(str) {
    console.log(str)
}
```

```js
// I will use this function, it makes it really easy to change later on.ah
    async function addEmoji(message, validReactions) {

        // Valid reactions = ["emoji", "emoji"]
        for (const reaction of validReactions) await message.react(reaction)

        // Define the filter. (const filter = ${condition})
        const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (!user.bot) // && (user.id == teacherID || devID.includes(user.id))

        // return the name of the emoji that the user reacted (with filters applied)
        return message
            .awaitReactions(filter, {
                max: 1 // max amount of reactions it will read, (1 = waits for one reaction so forth)
                    /* if you wanted to you could also add a time limit
                     * time: ${time} (int)
                     */
            })
            // grab the first emoji that was reacted
            .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
    }


    async function putYourHandsToTheSky(handMsg) {
        // Better to use this than what you have, if someone tries to explain the !talk command to someone it will run

        superConsole(`**@${handMsg.author.tag} asked to speak ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||**`)

        /* run the addEmoji function passing in :
         * the message variable,
         * and a array with the valid reactions that it will await for
         */

        const emoji = await addEmoji(handMsg, ["✅", "❎"])
        let myHomie = handMsg.guild.members.get(handMsg.author.id);

        if (emoji == "✅") {
            superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak given to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
            await myHomie.setMute(false)
            if (handMsg.deletable == true) {
                handMsg.delete() // deletes message, you can change this if you want. just cleans up my chat while testing this
            } else {
                superConsole(`I cannot delete this message! Role hierarchy I suppose...`)
            }
        } else if (emoji == "❎") {
            superConsole(`handRaiseMode | permission to speak denied to @${handMsg.author.tag} ||\`${handMsg.author.id}\`||`)
            if (handMsg.deletable == true) {
                handMsg.delete() // deletes message, you can change this if you want. just cleans up my chat while testing this
            } else {
                superConsole(`I cannot delete this message! Role hierarchy I suppose...`)
            }
        }
    }
    client.on('message', (handMsg) => {
        if (handMsg.content.startsWith(PREFIX + talk) && handMsg.channel.id == hgCID) {
            putYourHandsToTheSky(handMsg)
        }
    });
```